# How to dynamically extend class with method in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, inheritance, prototype

How to dynamically extend class with method in TypeScript? Any examples?
I try:

```
UsersBlocksMyOrders.prototype.myFunc = function():any{
  alert('23434');
};
```

But compiler give me a error.

Comment: What error it gives?

Comment: What's your purpose for `dynamically` extending a class?

Comment: Error: Property 'myFunc' does not exist on type 'UsersBlocksMyOrders'

Comment: I need dynamically extend class because I want to give to anyone extend with external javascript to add methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most often, you need to do something like:

```
interface UsersBlocksMyOrders {
    myFunc(): any;
}
```

Otherwise the compiler doesn't know about it.

---

It even works with existing classes. For example:

```
interface String {
    logit(): void;
}

String.prototype.logit = function () {
    console.log(this);
}

let a = "string";
a.logit();
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20String%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20logit()%3A%20void%3B%0A%7D%0A%0AString.prototype.logit%20%3D%20function%20()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(this)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Alet%20a%20%3D%20%22string%22%3B%0Aa.logit()%3B))

---

Because you want to change something in a different module, which is called [Module Augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation), you need to do something like:

```
Import { UsersBlocksMyOrders } from "../pages/users/blocks/myorders";

declare module "../pages/users/blocks/myorders" {
    interface UsersBlocksMyOrders {
        logit(): void;
    }
}

UsersBlocksMyOrders.prototype.logit = function () { console.log(this); }
```

Whenever possible (which it seems to be for you), edit the source code directly. Doing it like this should only be done on an as-needed basis.

Comment: It is does not work. Because class allready exists and it's conflict with declaration.

Comment: I try:
Import { UsersBlocksMyOrders } from "../pages/users/blocks/myorders";

interface UsersBlocksMyOrders {
  logit(): void;
}

UsersBlocksMyOrders.prototype.logit = function () {
  console.log(this);
}

It says: TS:2440 Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of UsersBlocksMyOrders

Comment: Check my revised answer. Also, next time don't put that much code in a comment as it's not readable. Instead edit your question and put it there and just comment saying that you've added it to the question.

Answer (score 2):

This may help ([from here](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)):

```
function extend<T, U>(first: T, second: U): T & U {
    let result = <T & U>{};
    for (let id in first) {
        (<any>result)[id] = (<any>first)[id];
    }
    for (let id in second) {
        if (!result.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
            (<any>result)[id] = (<any>second)[id];
        }
    }
    return result;
}

class Person {
    constructor(public name: string) { }
}
interface Loggable {
    log(): void;
}
class ConsoleLogger implements Loggable {
    log() {
        // ...
    }
}
var jim = extend(new Person("Jim"), new ConsoleLogger());
var n = jim.name;
jim.log();
```